# Put launcher icon at right

Tags: android

I want my launcher icon to be shown at the top right side of my android project instead of its default place that is top left. How can I do that?

I couldn't find any related and helpful example.

Thanks

Comment: You mean to show icon on right hand side of actionbar?

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

Comment: You Can use Custom layout.Ex:- actionBar = getSupportActionBar();  setCustomActionBar(R.layout.xxxxx); View view = actionBar.getCustomView();

Answer (score 1):

Following code worked for setting icon on top left corner(in ACTION BAR) :
The image name used is "conect_icon"

public void applyActionBar(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab,
            ActionBarActivity mContext,View
            custom) {
        ab = mContext.getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setCustomView(custom);
        ab.setTitle(R.string.st_action_title_main);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        ab.setLogo(R.drawable.conect_icon);
        ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    }

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you need your launcher icon to be shown in the right side of the actionbar instead of the left side. Although it is not suggested as a good practice by the UI patterns guidelines from the Android developer channel, you can do that by applying a customised Android actionbar. Use the following layout as your actionbar view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<!-- Place your launcher icon image view here -->    

</LinearLayout>
```

Then finally set the actionbar layout as follows.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

LayoutParams lp1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null); // your new layour

actionBar.setCustomView(customNav, lp1);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, and finally how should I set this actionBar as my project actionBar?